# HTML Header Semantics

Tags: html, semantics

I am doing a HTML semantics exercise as part of my University course and I ended up being curious as to which way headers should be laid out. Let me give 2 examples:

Example 1:

```
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>Main Header</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <header>
      <h1>Section Header</h1>
    </header>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Example 2:

```
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>Main Header</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <header>
      <h2>Section Header</h2>
    </header>
    <p>Content here</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

My main wonder here is wither you use a `h1` or `h2` inside the sections. If I understand right example 1 is more semantically correct as (at least in chrome) the raw html will style in such a way where the section headers are smaller. However, previously I have used the way in example 2, and in my class in year 1 I was never told this was incorrect.

Because I'm being graded on semantics in this exercise, and because I need to feed my curiosity, I'd love to know which is more correct.

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this question, so I've had to vote to close it as "primarily opinion-based". The [HTML5 specification specifically states](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections): "h1–h6 elements must not be used to markup subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for a new section or subsection." - meaning there's no reason why you couldn't use an infinite number of `h1` elements as long as they denote a new section on the page.

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/outlines/ is probably worth a read. Things might have changed a little since 2014 though, things were still in flux then IIRC.

Comment: Thanks James. I was hesitant to post this question as I thought that may be the case. I feel it was worth asking so I wasn't risking losing a grade through this exercise. I'll give that a read through Quentin.

Comment: I found this quote on W3C: "Sections may contain headings of a rank equal to their section nesting level. Authors should use headings of the appropriate rank for the section’s nesting level." followed by "correct" examples in example 2's style. For now I will continue using it. Consider this question closed as I do believe it is opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#headings-and-sections

> "Sections may contain headings of a rank equal to their section nesting level. Authors should use headings of the appropriate rank for the section’s nesting level."

Example 2 seems to be what W3C is suggesting to use in following examples after that quote.

This is probably all opinion based so I'm closing this question with this information.